# Image ignores container height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a row of widgets (what they are is irrelevant), each one in a fixed-width column. The first of these widgets is a collapsible image which is controlled by a button. The button will live in the same column as the image, and should be below it.

I can't seem to get the image to fit into the height of the parent element unless I use `height:100%;` in which case it pushes the button out. How can I resolve this issue?

Note: I use flexbox pretty heavily in this example, but you can remove that, there's no reason for it. The current code is not fixed-width, but it should be.

```js
function hideShow() {
  document.getElementById('hideme').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

main {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:rgba(0,255,0,50);
  display:flex;
}

main > div:first-child {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container > div:first-child > img {
  height:100%;
  /* Some code I can't figure out */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <img id="hideme" src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <button onclick="hideShow()">Show Image</button>
  </div>
  <button>Oh, and some</button>
  <input value="other stuff">
 </main>
```

Comment: In your case `main > div:first-child div {
  min-height: 0;
}
` will prove the dupe links explanation

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting thing to know. I had no idea flex included min-width/height defaults. The only problem I have now is making the width match the height, but that shouldn't be too hard. Thanks!